# Field Calculator Python Code for Between X-Y Calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to identify category based on two continuous variables and using IF ELSE logic for this.
[image: Current Code]

I intent to add elif statement, but even this code is throwing script error.

Both attributes are set to double, but I have also tried this by converting them to long int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is case sensitive so `AND` is not the same as `and`, lowercase is correct.

Also try enclosing both checks in one parenthesis:

```
if (10<=NMLY<=25 and 40<=GIDN<=70):
```